# How to set proper namespace for external class (FPDF)

Tags: php, namespaces

So I'm really lost at the moment, trying to find a way to use FPDF library that I got with composer. It's confused in my head so I hope I will be clear enough.

I have this composer file :

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.16",
        "setasign/fpdf": "1.8.1"
    },  
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PsyQuimper\\":"src/calendrier/php/"
        }
    }  
}
```

And an php file to require once all my classes from composer :

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I want to create bills with FPDF library. Here's the bill.php file start :

```
<?php

use \setasign\fpdf\FPDF;

class Bill extends FPDF {
    private $billString;
    private $billDate;

    function __construct($date) {
        $this->billDate = $date;
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Yet when I create a `new Bill('2015-05-05')` I have an error message :

> Class 'setasign\fpdf\FPDF' not found

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Anyone willing to enlight me here ?

EDIT :

I replaced `use \setasign\fpdf\FPDF;`
with `use FPDF`

simple as that. Thanks

Comment: did you try simply using `use FPDF;` instead ? I don't think the lib define the namespace you used there.

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks <3

Comment: Instead of relying on $_SERVER variables you should probably use __DIR__  to require autoload.php relatively. Also your Bill class should have the same namespace as the PSR-4 root defined in composer.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setasign/fpdf` does not use any namespaces: https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF/blob/1.8.1/fpdf.php.

You should pretend class name with `\` to indicate that class from global namespace should be used:

```
class Bill extends \FPDF
```

or import this class:

```
use FPDF;
```

However in your case your `Bill` class is not namespaced, so you can just remove `use \setasign\fpdf\FPDF;` and everything will use global namespace by default.

It is not strict convention to use than same namespace as package name - you need to look into documentation/code/`composer.json` to find actual namespace for dependencies.